# stack level too deep in new environment, works fine in existing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, stack, activesupport

I am getting this error message when I move my Ruby on Rails server over to a new machine. I've installed Ruby on Rails the exact same way as I have in the past but am now getting this error. I've verified that the permissions on the new server is correct and that everything is installed properly. Do you know why I would be getting this error on the new machine, but not the old existing one? Both are running production environments. If I run in Development environment on the new server then everything works properly.

```
SystemStackError in PagesController#index

stack level too deep

Rails.root: /var/ruby/fruit
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:422
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. I should be taken out back and just shoot myself in the face. When I restored my MySQL database, apparently the restore file was too large and it restored the development database just fine. However, the production database only got partially restored. LAME!